# Export + Import PSQL Table in PHP

Tags: php, database, psql

I have a languages tables in psql that look like this.

[image]

My goal is to export my languages table and import that back in using PHP.

**PHP**

Export

```
shell_exec('psql -E -U postgres -d portal -c "COPY languages TO \'/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/site/portal/public/csv/languages.csv\' DELIMITER \',\' "');
```

I got  `languages.csv` to export successfully.

If I open it up, it contain this.

```
1,h,Advanced Settings,Geavanceerde instellingen,Ajustes avanzados,Réglages avancés,2016-11-23 14:41:25,2016-11-23 14:41:25
```

---

Import

Now, I'm moving on to my import, here is what I did

```
shell_exec('psql -E -U postgres -d portal -c "COPY languages (code, text, nl, es, fr, created_at, updated_at) FROM \'/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/site/portal/public/csv/languages.csv\' DELIMITER \',\' csv;"');
```

I kept getting

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1,h,Advanced Settings,Geavanceerde instellingen,Ajustes avanzados,Réglages avancés,2016-11-23 14:41:25,2016-11-23 14:41:25"
```

CONTEXT:  COPY languages, line 1, column id: "1,h,Advanced Settings,Geavanceerde instellingen,Ajustes avanzados,Réglages avancés,2016-11-23 14:4..."

How do I fix this? Is it something with my export command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your COPY command for import has one less column than the CSV file. It's trying to grab your `updated_at` column as the second row's `code` field.

Table def:

```
(code, text, nl, es, fr, created_at, updated_at)
```

Row:

```
"1,h,Advanced Settings,Geavanceerde instellingen,Ajustes avanzados,Réglages avancés,2016-11-23 14:41:25,2016-11-23 14:41:25"
```

Map:

```
code - 1
text - "h"
nl - "Advanced Settings"
es - "Geavanceerde instellingen"
fr - "Ajustes avanzados"
created_at - "Réglages avancés"
updated_at - 2016-11-23 14:41:25
code2 - 2016-11-23 14:41:25 // <-- Problem
```

Comment: Thanks for your correction. Update to this `(id, code, text, nl, es, fr, created_at, updated_at)` is working like a charm now.